# multibranchPipelineJob Job DSL: How to enable Filter by name (with wildcards)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

How to enable in a Jenkins job DSL for a multibranch pipeline the behavior Filter by name (with wildcards). I tried it in following way but it didn't work.

configure {
def traits = it / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits
traits << 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.github__branch__source.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait' {
excludes("production")
includes("*")
}
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    traits << 'jenkins.scm.impl.trait.WildcardSCMHeadFilterTrait' {
        includes('master PR-*')
    }
```

worked for me to add the entry to behaviors.